# Jquery Datepicker serverside ReDraw?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, server-side, redraw

I have a view : dropdownmenu and 1 datepicker.
I want to update the datepicker with active (clickeable) days each time I change the menu. The problem is that the datepicker is updated with the new days (via jquery) but the effect isn't shown (redrawed) instantly, i had to change (month or year) so that the new values are shown at screen. helpppppp.

---

```
<select id="ServiceByAdmin" ....>
<option value="0"> .. </option><option value="4">.......</option></select>
<div id="CalendarContent" ...>
js :
var newdates=[];
$('#CalendarContent').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(d) {
  return [newdates[new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getDate())], ''];  }}); 
$("#ServiceByAdmin").change( function(event) {
       UpdateDates($('select option:selected').val());
        $('#CalendarContent').datepicker('refresh');
       }
```

---

I tried, refresh, hide/show, destroy. No method worked for me :(
note : the fct UpdateDates update the var newdates=[] with jquery request / php.

Thx 4 All

Answer (score 0):

```
var NewDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getDate());
$("[id$='" + TxtBoxid + "']").attr('value',NewDate);
```